# Trigger email or info when Selecting operation in particular table in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, email

when any user Selecting table like (select * from accounts) operation in particular table in mysql need a trigger or any notification

when user query like "select * from account;"

then it will automatically trigger a email.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and then rephrase your question, i.e. don't just dump requirements but include what you've tried or researched already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also search this type of trigger fire event in mysql
but unfortunately this type of event is not available.....

BD trigger can fire on `BEFOR or AFTER` `INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE` event

if you need to fire trigger event after `SELECT` query

i suggest you to do some thing by `JAVA` code

Comment: What i need to do in java for this process

Comment: I think your main program write in java ....  and you call select query from java code... You can write sample notification creation method in java ..... after geting select query data you call that notification method ..... This notification can sent a mail or store predefiend massage in DB( as your need)